# Use Fontawesome Icon for Background

Tags: font-awesome-5

I want to use a few icons as a background image. Like you would do with background-image, background-repeat and background-size.

Is it possible since it is an font?

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/IjJzL/

Answer (score 0):

With little Google search;

```
.btn {
  padding-left: 32px;
  position: relative;
}
.btn:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  content: "\f005";
}
```

Source: https://www.denisbouquet.com/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-css/